# How do you open a Compaq 15-s108na laptop?

Tags: windows-7

As the title says, idk how to do this. I've removed every screw and pulled at every join, I just can't disassemble the machine. I need to get the hard drive out. Help.

Sorry if you aren't supposed to ask about hardware problems here, but I don't know anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [service manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c04409502), you have to remove the keyboard (page 45) and the top cover (page 53) to access the hard drive (page 59). Note the hidden screws under the rubber feet.

Answer (score 0):

This is all going to be conjecture. Sorry. :/

Sometimes there's a final screw hidden underneath a sticker. Could that the issue?

Other times, you'll find that - now that you've removed all the screws - it's possible to open the machine back up, put it right side up and gently remove the keyboard. Then, underneath the keyboard will be another screw or three.